# Unknown column in 'field list' MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to populate a remote database but I am currently getting this error and I'm not sure how to fix this. The error refers to the first value I am trying to put into my table. I handled the events where `no eventID` would not be passed into the eventID table.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column '0654fac7' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
```

This is my code:

```
protected void loadToDatabase() {
    String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://remotehost/database";
    String usr = "username";
    String password = "";
    try {
        Connection Conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, usr, password);
        Statement stmt = Conn.createStatement();
        for (String i : eventIDs) {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO eventID VALUES (" + i + ");";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        }
        System.out.println("Insert complete");
    } catch (Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the data I am trying to pass into the database:

```
Test Case 0: 0654fac7-7aa8-4c55-bdaf-77b39692aa3f-1413318357238
Test Case 1: f9914577-c60d-49ae-bec6-4db0463676fd-1413318358598
Test Case 2: 6f1b6e4e-9d51-411b-8248-2cd9e1ef2712-1413318360005
Test Case 3: 330860b3-f22b-4b84-9837-bb949c2659ca-1413318361411
Test Case 4: no eventID
Test Case 5: e09f77f3-d816-49ab-90cd-4df56d8c8ef2-1413318366577
Test Case 6: f580e84e-7a3d-4693-bbea-454c5d699070-1413318367992
Test Case 7: no eventID
```

My database simply consists of one column.

```
mysql> show tables in eventID;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_eventID |
+-------------------+
| eventID           |
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the error I made was on this line of code

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO eventID VALUES (" + i + ");";
```

The correct functional code, because I am passing a string is:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO eventID VALUES (" + "\"" + i + "\"" + ");";
```

I need the quotation marks!

Comment: A PreparedStatement would avoid your problem, be faster, and would prevent sql injection.

Comment: works like charm thanks  String command = "INSERT INTO `products` (`ProductName`, `UnitPrice`) VALUES ("+"\""+name+"\""+","+"\"" +value+"\""+")";

Answer (score 2):

I have a litle code, to share.

This is my example table
++++++++++
ganaderos
++++++++++
CodGanadero
NomGanadero
ApeGanadero
++++++++++

```
        System.out.print("Ingrese codigo del Ganadero : ");
        CodigoGanadero= scn.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Ingrese Nombre del Ganadero : ");
        NombreGanadero=scn.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Ingrese Apellido del Ganadero : ");
        ApellidoGanadero=scn.nextLine();
        int rs2=0;
        rs2 = s2.executeUpdate ("insert into ganaderos (CodGanadero,NomGanadero,ApeGanadero) "
                + "values ("+"\""+CodigoGanadero+"\""+","+"\""+NombreGanadero+"\""+","+"\""+ApellidoGanadero+"\""+")");
```

Comment: Is a 3 camp, insertion on a table mysql.

I hope, help to someone.